# Is Times Ten Dialect supported by Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, timesten

Trying to use Oracle's Times Ten db instead of hsqldb for performance reasons.  I read where you need to create a new hibernate.jar file using times ten sql dialect class file.  This is proving to be a little challenging.  Does hibernate now work with times ten dialect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read where you need to create a new hibernate.jar file using times ten sql dialect class file.

Where did you read that? Unless you need change Hibernate, there is no need to recompile Hibernate to use a Dialect, as long as it's available on the classpath.

> Does hibernate now work with times ten dialect?

Never tried myself but Oracle's TimesTen 7 includes `org.hibernate.dialect.TimesTen7Dialect` that is supposed to work with newer versions (i.e. TimesTen 11g).

TimesTen dialects have been submitted for inclusion into Hibernate (see [HHH-3067](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3067)) but still aren't. So either download [TimesTen 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/timesten/downloads/index.html) (or maybe get it from [HHH-3061](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3061) but I can't say if they are similar).

Comment: http://www.oracle.com//technetwork/database/timesten/wp-timesten70-appsrv-128860.pdf

Comment: At the end of the PDF mentions recompiling. After review it appears that you just need to include the timeten7dialect.java file. However we have hibernate working with times ten 11G without doing that step.